# Windows Azure MVC3 app - 500 - Internal server error

Tags: azure

I was running my application with no errors locally, but when added Windows Azure project, set up the database config, generated the packages and ran in stage mode, I just can get 500 internal errors.

My app has some redirections for logged and non logged users.

I tried to follow some answers about the problem with no results. When I run the application locally with the emulator everything runs ok.

I didn't set any permission or user anywhere in my SQL or Windows Azure panel. As I don't have any experience with Windows Azure, please explain steps on how to do things =)

Comment: maybe you got 500 programming errors :D?

Comment: Maybe, but if I can't see these errors its impossible to solve the problems. How to display errors?

Comment: See my blog on Debugging Azure HTTP 500 Errors http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/11/06/debugging-azure-http-500-errors.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, after reading almost 20 articles, I realized that I was using the old Membership and Session Providers, and that the old aspnet_regsql doesn't fit Windows Azure.

So, the first action of my application was watch if the user was logged in. Because of that, the 500 Internal errors.

Articles that helped me a lot:

http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2011/06/21/using-the-asp.net-membership-api-wish-sql-server--sql.aspx

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx